# Is my Twitter Bootstrap's ScrollSpy trying to spy elements not supposed to be spied?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, scroll, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using BackboneJS and Bootstrap, and I was trying to enable scroll spy on some content after the visitor clicks on a button.

So when the user clicks on that button, these gets executed:

```
$('#frontPageNav').css('display', 'block'); // It was hidden on load
$('#frontPageNav').scrollspy(); // Activate scrollspy, this is where the error happens
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
  var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh'); // I think this is not needed because nothing was invisible before
});
$('#frontPageNav li').on('activate', function () { // This never gets emitted
  alert('activate!');
});
```

And the content I'd like to be spied is placed like this:

```
<div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#frontPageNav">
  <div id="home-top" class="row slide">
  </div>
  <div id="home-how" class="row slide">
  </div>
  <div id="home-join" class="row slide">
  </div>
</div>
```

No other element on the page has the data-spy attribute, so I think this is supposed to be the only content spied, but apparently not: On page load I get an error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null`, which means the scrollspy plugin is attempting to find the `$.position()` of an element that does not exist. I turned on the exception brakes in Chrome's developer tools, and the uncaught exception is in line 454 of bootstrap.js, which is `&& [[$href.position().top, href]]) || null` and if I hover `href`, the selector is for an element that I don't have in my markup, but I have a link to a hash with that.

Does this mean that the scrollspy plugin thinks it's supposed to spy all links with `href="#something"` and find in the markup elements with that ID ? Why isn't it keeping the spying action to the elements with `data-spy="scroll"` ?

Answer (score 5):

By attaching the ScrollSpy plugin to a specific element, the plugin will listen for scroll events on that element.  However, the plugin uses the **target** option to determine which links are eligible for activating.  Unless a **target** is explicitly supplied, the ScrollSpy plugin will scrape the *entire body* for links which match the selector `'.nav li > a'`.  By supplying a **target**, the selector will become `target + ' .nav li > a'`, confining the search to within the **target**.

The API supports specification through markup using `data-target`, as well as by passing it as an option in the JavaScript call `$('#myElement').scrollspy({target: '#myTarget'});`.

A more extensive description of how the ScrollSpy plugin works can be found in [an answer to **How to activate links for Twitter Bootstrap Affix component?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12125450/570918)