# How to activate links for Twitter Bootstrap Affix component?

Tags: jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Twitter Bootstrap Affix JS component. My UL list is affixing properly when I scroll the page down. Also - when I click on the individual list items (much like Twitter does on its docs page), it scrolls down to my anchor ID in my document, but the LI element does not receive the Twitter 'active' class. Nor does it get the 'active' class when I scroll my document.

I would expect the appropriate link to be active when I have scrolled to the particular part in the document (much like scroll-spy works), but I can't seem to get this to work.

Is there something special I need to set up so that Bootstrap will add the 'active' class when appropriate?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you need to also use the ScrollSpy plugin.  You can activate it through markup or through JS.  Letting `#scroll-pane` be the element that triggers **scroll** events and `#navbar` be the element containing the `ul.nav`, the following should get it working:

### HTML

```html
<div id="scroll-pane" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">
```

### JS

```js
$('#scroll-pane').scrollspy({target: '#navbar'});
```

Use either the HTML or the JS, but not both.

---

#### Additional Info

When the ScrollSpy plugin is passed a target, like `scrollspy({target: '#navbar'})`, this is used to construct a selector of the form

```
target + ' .nav li > a'
```

which, in this example would give

```
'#navbar .nav li > a'
```

It is important to understand the stipulations that this selector creates.

1. The original `target` must be an element which *contains* an element with class `nav`. So `.nav` should probably never be your target.
2. The `.nav` element must contain list items.
3. Those list items must have a `<a>` as a direct child.

The `<a>` elements selected by this are then filtered out by those whose `data-target` or `href` begin with a '#'.  These `href`'s are in turn used to select the elements contained in the element to which the ScrollSpy plugin is attached.  Offsets of those selected are stored, and when a scroll occurs, a comparison of the current scroll offset is made with the stored values, updating the corresponding `<a>` element with the class `active`.

Hopefully, this summary can aid in better understanding what one might be tripping over when attempting to implement the plugin, without having to dig into the code in further detail.

Comment: I have tried this actually - but it doesn't make a difference. So on my body tag I have set up those two data attributes, with the data-target one pointing to the class of my UL list. I have also added two additional classes to my UL, namely .nav and .nav-list in the hope that that would make a difference - but still no effect.

Comment: @Joerg Target should be the `<div>`, which *contains* the `ul.nav-list`, not the `<ul>` itself. For example, on the Bootstrap docs page, the target is `.bs-docs-sidebar`, which is a `<div>`.

Comment: @Joerg Sorry, I misstated that the first time.  The `<ul>` needs to have the class `nav` to be selected, not `nav-list`.  That doesn't necessarily mean you need to remove the `nav-list`, but you do need to make sure the `<ul>` (or something between it and your target) has the class `nav`.  Forgive me if that was a point of confusion.

Comment: This was a great explanation... FYI to get my desired effect (same one as on the Twitter Bootstrap docs page) I needed to set 'body' as my target element...would not work with the immediate parent of the elements I wanted to spy.